# What is the purpose of injecting HttpContextBase in Controller with IoC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, autofac

I've seen lots of code samples using an IoC Container with registrations such as:

```
// Autofac
builder.Register(c => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current))
            .As<HttpContextBase>()
            .InstancePerRequest();

// Again Autofac 
builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacWebTypesModule());
```

(see src for AutofacWebTypesModule [HERE](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/master/Core/Source/Autofac.Integration.Mvc/AutofacWebTypesModule.cs) )

```
// Castle Windsor
container.Register(Component.For<HttpContextBase()
                  .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest
                  .UsingFactoryMethod(() => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current)));
```

Together with controllers using contructor injection:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly HttpContextBase _httpContext;

    public HomeController(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        _httpContext = httpContext;
    }
    //....
}
```

#### Question 1:

Can you please explain the reason of wrapping HttpContextBase,HttpRequestBase and so on..?

#### Question 2:

What would be the difference between the **Injected HttpContextBase** vs **HttpContext** (Controller's property) vs **System.Web.HttpContext.Current**

### Update

#### Question 3:

Which HttpContext to use in code, the **Injected One** or it is also good to call it through **HttpContext** and **System.Web.HttpContext.Current**? Are there any issues if calling both ways?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer 1**

`HttpContext` is a notorious pain when it comes to testing, since it only exists in the context of a request. [Since .net 3.5 `HttpContextBase` is an abstraction of `HttpContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextbase%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and lends itself to being injected through IOC frameworks

By letting the IOC container handle it you can register a different/deterministic instance be injected into your components at test time. In normal code you would inject the `HttpContextWrapper` that is the default implementation

From the linked page:

> The HttpContextBase class is an abstract class that contains the same
>   members as the HttpContext class. The HttpContextBase class enables
>   you to create derived classes that are like the HttpContext class, but
>   that you can customize and that work outside the ASP.NET pipeline.
>   When you perform unit testing, you typically use a derived class to
>   implement members with customized behavior that fulfills the scenario
>   you are testing.

**Answer 2**

The injected `HttpContextBase` would return data that is needed in order for the test to succeed: a specific query string, a specific query, etc. Usually the injected implementation would only contain the needed methods for the test, ignoring all others, e.g the context `.User.Identity.Name` property in order to test authentication.

**Answer 3**

In code, you must always use the `HttpContextBase` that is injected, since you don't want to depend on a concrete implementation that may fail at test time. If calling both ways you may encounter problems, most notably in tests since the `HttpContext.Current` will return null.

Comment: Hmm now I understand that is also done for testing purposes. One more to go : So If there are any dependent solution class libraries wich use HttpContext.Current, then should I refactor them, in order to use HttpContextBase from constructor ?

Comment: Yes, but you can do this progressively as you bring them into a test harness. The problem doesn't exist as long as you are not trying to use the classes out of a web stack, but as soon as they must be tested you will encounter this problem, and will need to refactor to address it

Comment: And here is an example, using StructureMap: `For<HttpContextBase>().Use(() => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current));`